# Linux : Disabling File cache for a process?

Tags: linux, performance, caching, file-io, io

Is there a way to disable file cache for a particular process ?

I have two process running A and B.

I want file opened by A to remain in cache.

and 
I don't want to enable file cache for B so It doesn't replace the file cached by process in the memory.

Is there a way to disable file cache for a particular process?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve, or is this just academic curiosity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeping a file in the OS block buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130916/keeping-a-file-in-the-os-block-buffer)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams
According to the performance test we had done for process A. 
If file-cache is in memory then it is taking 20-30 ms to process the file. 
But if it getting loaded from disk it is taking 300-400 ms to process. 
I want to avoid this time delay by keeping file cache in memory. 
Is there any way to solve this issue ?

Comment: @VivekGoel I think yes - it is called memory-mapped files, please see the UPDATE to my answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None that I know of... the only option are global/device-specific:

- using -sync option with mount
- using [drop_caches](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_drop_caches.html)

Another point:

Even IF you could do what you ask for there is no guarantee that any other processes (C, D, E etc.) behaves in a way that "the file cached by process A in the memory" gets replaced...

**UPDATE - after comments from OP ragarding performance:**

Linux offers (as most modern OS) something called "memory-mapped file" - basically this is a way to access the file's contents in-memory... the OS assigns the file (depending on the given params) part of the address space and loads the content of the file into that address space (again: exact behaviour depends on the given params).

You would do this in Process A to achieve what you want...

Checkout the [`mmap` API calls](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Process B could use `fadvise()` to direct the kernel to not cache data read from a given file descriptor.

Comment: AFAIK calling `fadvice` (param FADV_DONTNEED  ?) does not mean that the kernel will strictly follow the instruction - it is more of a "hint" this call gives the kernel...

Comment: Correct. However, `FADV_DONTNEED` does currently have the behavior of removing the appropriate pages from the cache.