# Performance of "database-indexed + stored in random file" vs "stored in database"

Tags: python, database-performance, random-access

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614120/about-the-speed-of-random-file-read-python) I posted some code and asked some questions, once again the code:

```
index = db.open()
fh = open('somefile.txt','rb')
for i in range(1000):
    x = random_integer(1,5000)
    pos,length = index[x]
    fh.seek(pos)
    buffer = fh.read(length)

    doSomeThingWith(buffer)

fh.close()
db.close()
```

Inspired by a module called ["Corpora"](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Corpora/1.0) I used a database to index the positions and lengths of text segments in a .txt file for random retrieval. I'll call this solution "database+file" in the rest of this post.

When "database+file" code is run repeatedly, the execution takes less and less time. And I compared the performance of this solution with using BerkeleyDB to store those text segments. By adjusting the pagesize, BerkeleyDB solution's performance was fine-tuned  to its best.

I put the codes of both solutions in one script. The results of six consecutive retrievals from BDB+File and BDB are as follow:

[image: Comparison results of BDB+File vs BDB]

**Can I judge that the random read speed of "database+file" is something like "fast enough"?**

P.s. I am looking for a solution for storing texts and text segments of a structured corpus. Database can be helpful, but evidently storing a large amount of texts of diverse lengths in database is not a good idea. I am evaluating the "database+file" solution, i.e. using database to build up the structure of corpus and storing all texts and text segments in plain random access file, and the database only store the pointers. Extraction of text segments is just plain random access operation. I need to determine whether the performance of this solution is good enough. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Fast enough for what? ;-) Seriously, it's unclear what you're trying to find out.

Comment: @TimPeters: Yes, it is kind of unclear. I mean is it safe to say at least this "database+file" is not too slow to be a solution for storing a corpus of texts?